# why is "+" added to all my coordinates in url builder?

Tags: java, string, url, format, coordinates

I have this code to build a string of coordinates:

```
public String generateUrl(CompleteRoutingResponseShort completeRoutingResponse) {

    if (completeRoutingResponse == null)
    {
        return "CompleteRoutingResponse is null";
    }

    UriBuilder builder = UriBuilder
            .fromPath(Constants.LIVEMAP_BASE_URL)
            .scheme("http");

    builder.queryParam("lineGeom", getCoordsLists(completeRoutingResponse));
    return builder.build().toString();
}

    private String getCoordsLists() {

        List<String> lists = new ArrayList<>();
        for (AlternativeShort alternative : completeRoutingResponses.alternatives)
        {
            String list  =  "( " + alternative.coords.stream().map(item -> String.format("%.4f , %.4f", item.x, item.y))
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")) + ")";

//            list.replace("+","");
            lists.add(list);
        }

        return String.join(", ", lists);
    }
```

however I get this url as an output:

```
"http:/myhost.com/tiles/internal?lineGeom=(+34.9178+,+31.9550,+34.9175+,+31.9552,+34.9174+,+31.9553,+34.9172+,+31.9555,+34.9171+,+31.9556,+34.9171+,+31.9556,+34.9168+,+31.9559,+34.9168+,+31.9559,+34.9167+,+31.9561,+34.9165+,+31.9562,+34.9164+,+31.9564,+34.9161+,+31.9567,+34.9161+,+31.9568,+34.9160+,+31.9570,+34.9159+,+31.9571,+34.9158+,+31.9572,+34.9158+,+31.9573,+34.9157+,+31.9574,+34.9157+,+31.9574,+34.9166+,+31.9577,+34.9166+,+31.9577,+34.9178+,+31.9581,+34.9184+,+31.9583,+34.9188+,+31.9583,+34.9192+,+31.9584,+34.9195+,+31.9585,+34.9201+,+31.9585,+34.9204+,+31.9585,+34.9208+,+31.9585,+34.9211+,+31.9585,+34.9214+,+31.9585,+34.9216+,+31.9585,+34.9222+,+31.9584,+34.9224+,+31.9584,+34.9227+,+31.9583,+34.9233+,+31.9582,+34.9233+,+31.9582,+34.9238+,+31.9580,+34.9246+,+31.9577,+34.9257+,+31.9572,+34.9262+,+31.9571,+34.9265+,+31.9569,+34.9266+,+31.9569,+34.9268+,+31.9569,+34.9271+,+31.9568,+34.9276+,+31.9567,+34.9281+,+31.9566,+34.9284+,+31.9566,+34.9289+,+31.9566,+34.9307+,+31.9565,+34.9314+,+31.9564,+34.9320+,+31.9564,+34.9325+,+31.9563,+34.9325+,+31.9563,+34.9330+,+31.9563,+34.9335+,+31.9563,+34.9340+,+31.9562,+34.9345+,+31.9562,+34.9345+,+31.9562,+34.9357+,+31.9560,+34.9361+,+31.9560,+34.9365+,+31.9559,+34.9365+,+31.9559,+34.9369+,+31.9559,+34.9373+,+31.9558,+34.9373+,+31.9558,+34.9376+,+31.9557,+34.9377+,+31.9556,+34.9382+,+31.9554,+34.9387+,+31.9549,+34.9387+,+31.9549,+34.9389+,+31.9547,+34.9394+,+31.9542,+34.9394+,+31.9542,+34.9395+,+31.9543,+34.9395+,+31.9543,+34.9398+,+31.9545,+34.9399+,+31.9546,+34.9399+,+31.9546,+34.9401+,+31.9548,+34.9407+,+31.9555,+34.9414+,+31.9565,+34.9417+,+31.9571,+34.9417+,+31.9571,+34.9418+,+31.9572,+34.9418+,+31.9572,+34.9420+,+31.9578,+34.9420+,+31.9579,+34.9421+,+31.9585,+34.9421+,+31.9585,+34.9421+,+31.9590,+34.9421+,+31.9599,+34.9421+,+31.9599,+34.9422+,+31.9607,+34.9422+,+31.9608,+34.9423+,+31.9609,+34.9423+,+31.9610,+34.9423+,+31.9610,+34.9423+,+31.9611,+34.9424+,+31.9611,+34.9425+,+31.9612,+34.9426+,+31.9613,+34.9426+,+31.9613,+34.9426+,+31.9613,+34.9429+,+31.9616,+34.9432+,+31.9618,+34.9436+,+31.9621,+34.9449+,+31.9630,+34.9449+,+31.9630,+34.9487+,+31.9649,+34.9487+,+31.9649,+34.9525+,+31.9668,+34.9525+,+31.9668,+34.9531+,+31.9671,+34.9535+,+31.9672,+34.9538+,+31.9674,+34.9542+,+31.9676,+34.9546+,+31.9678,+34.9550+,+31.9680,+34.9553+,+31.9682,+34.9554+,+31.9682,+34.9558+,+31.9684,+34.9566+,+31.9689,+34.9570+,+31.9691,+34.9573+,+31.9694,+34.9579+,+31.9698,+34.9582+,+31.9701,+34.9586+,+31.9704,+34.9591+,+31.9709,+34.9594+,+31.9713,+34.9599+,+31.9720,+34.9602+,+31.9725,+34.9605+,+31.9730,+34.9608+,+31.9736,+34.9610+,+31.9742,+34.9612+,+31.9746,+34.9613+,+31.9752,+34.9614+,+31.9756,+34.9615+,+31.9764,+34.9627+,+31.9857,+34.9630+,+31.9883,+34.9632+,+31.9892,+34.9634+,+31.9902,+34.9637+,+31.9912,+34.9654+,+31.9961,+34.9658+,+31.9974,+34.9659+,+31.9979,+34.9660+,+31.9984,+34.9662+,+31.9994,+34.9663+,+32.0002,+34.9664+,+32.0011,+34.9671+,+32.0154,+34.9671+,+32.0166,+34.9671+,+32.0169,+34.9671+,+32.0176,+34.9670+,+32.0179,+34.9669+,+32.0185,+34.9668+,+32.0192,+34.9666+,+32.0198,+34.9663+,+32.0206,+34.9660+,+32.0211,+34.9656+,+32.0218,+34.9652+,+32.0225,+34.9649+,+32.0229,+34.9644+,+32.0236,+34.9627+,+32.0256,+34.9607+,+32.0279,+34.9602+,+32.0285,+34.9596+,+32.0292,+34.9587+,+32.0300,+34.9534+,+32.0351,+34.9530+,+32.0356,+34.9525+,+32.0361,+34.9520+,+32.0368,+34.9515+,+32.0374,+34.9414+,+32.0522,+34.9408+,+32.0531,+34.9404+,+32.0539,+34.9399+,+32.0548,+34.9396+,+32.0555,+34.9392+,+32.0567,+34.9381+,+32.0603,+34.9381+,+32.0603,+34.9357+,+32.0679,+34.9357+,+32.0679,+34.9341+,+32.0730,+34.9341+,+32.0730,+34.9336+,+32.0747,+34.9331+,+32.0765,+34.9331+,+32.0765,+34.9330+,+32.0767,+34.9330+,+32.0768,+34.9328+,+32.0781,+34.9328+,+32.0781,+34.9328+,+32.0793,+34.9328+,+32.0793,+34.9333+,+32.0832,+34.9341+,+32.0899,+34.9351+,+32.0989,+34.9358+,+32.1057,+34.9359+,+32.1064,+34.9359+,+32.1064,+34.9359+,+32.1075,+34.9361+,+32.1093,+34.9363+,+32.1106,+34.9366+,+32.1119,+34.9369+,+32.1130,+34.9369+,+32.1131,+34.9373+,+32.1141,+34.9375+,+32.1146,+34.9381+,+32.1159,+34.9387+,+32.1171,+34.9391+,+32.1178,+34.9391+,+32.1178,+34.9399+,+32.1189,+34.9403+,+32.1195,+34.9410+,+32.1204,+34.9411+,+32.1204,+34.9414+,+32.1208,+34.9442+,+32.1238,+34.9477+,+32.1273,+34.9477+,+32.1273,+34.9497+,+32.1294,+34.9497+,+32.1294,+34.9533+,+32.1331,+34.9533+,+32.1331,+34.9554+,+32.1350,+34.9556+,+32.1351,+34.9558+,+32.1352,+34.9562+,+32.1354,+34.9564+,+32.1355,+34.9566+,+32.1355,+34.9578+,+32.1358,+34.9582+,+32.1360,+34.9586+,+32.1361,+34.9589+,+32.1363,+34.9591+,+32.1364,+34.9593+,+32.1366,+34.9595+,+32.1368,+34.9596+,+32.1370,+34.9598+,+32.1372,+34.9598+,+32.1374,+34.9599+,+32.1377,+34.9600+,+32.1379,+34.9600+,+32.1381,+34.9600+,+32.1383,+34.9599+,+32.1385,+34.9599+,+32.1387,+34.9598+,+32.1389,+34.9597+,+32.1392,+34.9596+,+32.1393,+34.9595+,+32.1395,+34.9594+,+32.1397,+34.9592+,+32.1399,+34.9591+,+32.1400,+34.9589+,+32.1402,+34.9587+,+32.1403,+34.9560+,+32.1421,+34.9560+,+32.1421,+34.9515+,+32.1449,+34.9515+,+32.1449,+34.9513+,+32.1451,+34.9513+,+32.1451,+34.9509+,+32.1453,+34.9509+,+32.1453,+34.9504+,+32.1457,+34.9504+,+32.1457,+34.9456+,+32.1488,+34.9439+,+32.1500,+34.9431+,+32.1505,+34.9431+,+32.1505,+34.9423+,+32.1512,+34.9403+,+32.1527,+34.9399+,+32.1531,+34.9371+,+32.1556,+34.9324+,+32.1598,+34.9297+,+32.1622,+34.9297+,+32.1622,+34.9280+,+32.1635,+34.9265+,+32.1645,+34.9254+,+32.1650,+34.9237+,+32.1658,+34.9237+,+32.1658,+34.9237+,+32.1658,+34.9235+,+32.1659,+34.9223+,+32.1663,+34.9213+,+32.1665,+34.9209+,+32.1666,+34.9207+,+32.1667,+34.9196+,+32.1670,+34.9167+,+32.1676,+34.9167+,+32.1676,+34.9146+,+32.1681,+34.9124+,+32.1686,+34.9121+,+32.1686,+34.9112+,+32.1688,+34.9101+,+32.1689,+34.9089+,+32.1690,+34.9065+,+32.1693,+34.9056+,+32.1694,+34.9045+,+32.1695,+34.9038+,+32.1697,+34.9032+,+32.1698,+34.9031+,+32.1698,+34.9025+,+32.1700,+34.9022+,+32.1701,+34.9018+,+32.1702,+34.9015+,+32.1703,+34.9002+,+32.1708,+34.8985+,+32.1714,+34.8985+,+32.1714,+34.8982+,+32.1714,+34.8981+,+32.1714,+34.8977+,+32.1714,+34.8975+,+32.1714,+34.8972+,+32.1714,+34.8970+,+32.1714,+34.8963+,+32.1716,+34.8938+,+32.1721,+34.8935+,+32.1722,+34.8935+,+32.1722,+34.8935+,+32.1723,+34.8935+,+32.1723,+34.8935+,+32.1727,+34.8935+,+32.1727,+34.8935+,+32.1728,+34.8935+,+32.1729,+34.8935+,+32.1729,+34.8935+,+32.1730,+34.8934+,+32.1732,+34.8933+,+32.1734,+34.8933+,+32.1734,+34.8922+,+32.1744,+34.8922+,+32.1744,+34.8913+,+32.1753,+34.8913+,+32.1753,+34.8906+,+32.1761,+34.8906+,+32.1761,+34.8903+,+32.1763,+34.8899+,+32.1769,+34.8896+,+32.1772,+34.8896+,+32.1772,+34.8891+,+32.1775,+34.8887+,+32.1778,+34.8886+,+32.1781,+34.8886+,+32.1781,+34.8891+,+32.1804,+34.8891+,+32.1804,+34.8893+,+32.1812,+34.8893+,+32.1812,+34.8900+,+32.1846,+34.8900+,+32.1846,+34.8902+,+32.1853,+34.8902+,+32.1856,+34.8902+,+32.1857,+34.8898+,+32.1886,+34.8898+,+32.1886,+34.8896+,+32.1896,+34.8896+,+32.1896,+34.8893+,+32.1912,+34.8893+,+32.1914,+34.8892+,+32.1916,+34.8892+,+32.1917,+34.8893+,+32.1919,+34.8893+,+32.1920,+34.8894+,+32.1920,+34.8895+,+32.1921,+34.8896+,+32.1922,+34.8897+,+32.1922,+34.8899+,+32.1922,+34.8900+,+32.1922,+34.8902+,+32.1922,+34.8903+,+32.1921,+34.8903+,+32.1920,+34.8904+,+32.1919,+34.8904+,+32.1918,+34.8905+,+32.1917,+34.8905+,+32.1916,+34.8904+,+32.1912,+34.8904+,+32.1912,+34.8898+,+32.1911,+34.8898+,+32.1911,+34.8891+,+32.1911,+34.8891+,+32.1911,+34.8885+,+32.1910,+34.8872+,+32.1912,+34.8872+,+32.1912,+34.8858+,+32.1913,+34.8858+,+32.1913,+34.8848+,+32.1914,+34.8844+,+32.1915,+34.8844+,+32.1915,+34.8838+,+32.1916,+34.8838+,+32.1916,+34.8820+,+32.1920,+34.8820+,+32.1920,+34.8811+,+32.1922,+34.8811+,+32.1922,+34.8810+,+32.1925,+34.8810+,+32.1928,+34.8810+,+32.1928,+34.8808+,+32.1934,+34.8808+,+32.1934,+34.8807+,+32.1940,+34.8807+,+32.1940,+34.8805+,+32.1953,+34.8805+,+32.1953,+34.8805+,+32.1958)",
```

how can I remove the `+` signs ?

Comment: URLs cannot contain spaces. They have to be encoded as either `+` or `%20`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis warning; + is a query part is literal. It is only a space in POST data

Comment: Where does the class `UriBuilder` come from? That class is probably encoding the spaces as `+` or `%20` sequences because, as Phylogenesis points out, raw spaces are not permitted in a URL.

Comment: My guess is that the String.format is doing that. Can u use Joiner from Guava instead of doing it by hand? (on the getCoordsLists method).

Comment: You also have the solution to use [URI templates](https://github.com/fge/uri-template) instead; they are very powerful and can probably achieve what you want. Not sure also why you insist on spaces between the commas?

Comment: can you please write as an answer and I'll mark as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your getCoordsLists() method you are joining the collectors with `", "`
thats why, after building the url it is adding spaces after every coordinate.

so just replace the `", "` with `","` in the following line:

```
            String list  =  "( " + alternative.coords.stream().map(item -> String.format("%.4f , %.4f", item.x, item.y))
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")) + ")";
```

It is happening because default url encoder is replacing the spaces by "+" so that the link will not be broken.

You should also replace the last line in the same way, where you are returning the string.